# PHP concatenate multiple modes in MySQL SET MODE statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with this PHP code to set MySQL **session** Mode:

```
$query = "SET sql_mode = $newmode";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

The value below works correctly and all MySQL Modes are disabled:

```
$newmode ="''";
```

This also works correctly:

```
$newmode = "ANSI";
```

but, if I combine modes, e.g.

```
$newmode ="HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE,IGNORE_SPACE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER";
```

it does not work -- the default Global Mode is set for the session.

I have tried disabling all modes first and then issuing the SET statement, but nothing works for me.

Anyone know how to concatenate modes in a MySQL SET SESSION statement?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the quotes.

When clearing `$newmode` you're giving `''` as value, so the SQL would look like `sql_mode=''`.

When adding more options to `$newmode`, you simply forget the quotes so the SQL looks like `sql_mode=HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE,IGNORE_SPACE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER`, which may result is a syntax error.

Pay attention to the quotes and try this solution:

```
//$newmode = "";
//$newmode = "ANSI";
$newmode = "HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE,IGNORE_SPACE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER";

$query = "SET sql_mode = '$newmode'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: It would be better to supply this as a placeholder value and use `bind_param`.

Comment: Not actually needed if `$newmode` is just set by the code and no user input.

Comment: It's a better practice to be in the habit of placeholdering anything that *might* contain problematic characters rather than assuming it doesn't. A query with a `$` in it should be flagged during a code review and if it isn't strictly necessary, it shouldn't be there.